# If connecting directly to a modem, how are DNS lookups performed?

Tags: router, dns, internet, modem

From my own experience, when connecting a device to a router and leaving everything at their default settings, the connected device will typically use the DNS servers of the ISP in question as pushed by the router. Taking the above into account, what DNS servers are used if connecting a device directly to the Ethernet port of a modem - do modems also have their own DNS settings that are pushed to clients, or are DNS lookups performed differently in this situation?

Comment: if you connect to a modem, it will get the dns server from the ISP providing DHCP server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, yes.

A router is basically a bridge between the WAN port and the LAN ports, where the WAN port goes to the modem.

When a router makes a connection to the internet, it can do so through a few different protocols. PPPoE, DHCP and Static are common. PPPoE and Static basically make you enter the connection settings into the modem and DHCP means, whatever the provider gives you.

PPPoE and Static are not used often anymore to my knowledge because DHCP is easier to manage.

For that reason, I'm going to explain the DHCP variant only.

The ISP has a DHCP server in their network. When you get internet, a mechanic will patch your internet connection to their internet server. This allows your internet port (can be phone, cable, etc) to automatically be connected inside the network of your ISP. Your modem, when set to auto DHCP will request information from the DHCP server, and configure itself based on these settings.

This will set its own WAN IP address, and DNS servers.

The Modem also has a LAN port. If It is only a modem, not a router, the modem will simply push the DHCP information to LAN 1, so your computer's local IP Address becomes the WAN Ip Address, and all ports are open. Your DNS servers are set to the ISP's DNS servers.

If you add a router in the mix (either the modem is a modem/router or there is a separate router device) the router will have these settings on the WAN port, and all LAN ports will be on a new network with its own DHCP server. This network is completely shielded from the WAN network, but is bridged by the router itself.

Any request from and to the router from and to the internet will be processed by the router itself. Incoming requests will be processed by NAT, outgoing requests will be forwarded and optionally, if uPNP is enabled and supported, additional ports for incoming requests are opened.

So yes, your modem gets the DNS server simply through the DHCP server from your ISP.

This doesn't mean you always have to use this. You can simply override it by any other server and then the ISP's DNS servers are not used. Traffic still goes through the ISP, but the translation from Domainname to IP address (which is what DNS does) does not has to be happening on the DNS servers from you ISP.

Answer (score 1):

There are three main ways for your computer to learn what DNS server IP addresses to use: DHCP, PPP, and manual configuration.

If your modem setup doesn't require your computer to run a PPPoE client, then your computer usually learns what DNS server IP address to use via DHCP. If your modem is just a transparent bridging modem, then it will forward you DHCP requests along to the ISP, and the ISP's DHCP server will reply. If your modem is more than just a modem; that is, if it's also capable of acting as a NAT gateway router as most modern "modems" are nowadays, then it's possible that your modem is running a local DHCP server that responds to your computer's DHCP request. In this case, your "modem" (really in this case it's being a combo "modem/gateway") will have learned those DNS server IP addresses via PPP negotiation (read on).

If your modem setup requires your computer to run a PPPoE client, then your computer learns what DNS server IP addresses to use via the PPP negotiation; specifically, the IPCP negotiation.

It's also possible to manually configure your computer's networking stack to use certain DNS server IP addresses. This is known as "manual" or "static" configuration.